# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource origin null

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, jax-rs

I am learning jax-rs and i am not able to solve this issue. I have already checked issue related to origin 'null' in internet and about CORS. I have done everything but still i keep getting this error in browser console.

```
  $.ajax({
async: true,
crossDomain: true,
url: "http://localhost:8081/messenger/login",
type: 'post',
dataType:'json',
processData: false,
data: '{"email":"test"}',
success:function(data){
  console.log(data);
},
error : function(data) {
  console.log(data);;
}  });
```

and my jax-rs resource class

```
@Path("/messenger")
public class DispatcherServlet {

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response login(ProfileModel profileModel){
        System.out.println("test login "+profileModel);
        return Response.ok().header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8081").build();
    }
}
```

I am using jetty server and running my code at port 8081.
any help guys

Comment: is the html served on `localhost:8081`

Comment: try to add @CrossOrigin on your DispatcherServlet class

Comment: no html file is not on localhost. i am using file system to open html in browser

Comment: well, you've only allowed requests **from** `http://localhost:8081/` - i.e. it makes **no sense** from `http://localhost:8081` to issue `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8081` - because that would be a same domain request - plus `file:///` accessing `http://` will never work

Comment: Thanks guys i have hosted my html files in local server webapp. now i dont get that issue anymore. Thanks a lot